# Adding File Upload Functionality to Existing Bootstrap Form

Tags: php, file-upload, contact-form

My site is here: [vectormaid.com](http://www.vectormaid.com)

I used a bootstrap template I liked with an existing contact form that only needed my email to work.  I want to add a file upload to this form.  I've already designed the button to my liking, and it functions well (you can select multiple files and they show as being selected within the form).

How do I add the php functionality to get the file upload portion to work?  Everything else sends in an email just fine, so I know the form is working minus the file upload.

Here's my php for the form:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'artwork@vectormaid.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@vectormaid.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Comment: upload file to your host some folder and share the URL with host URL+foldername+filename

Comment: I would use https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ and add the file as an attachment.